# Different Colors in different rows in table

Tags: tables

[image]

How can I remove the small white line appears in the heading of this table?

My code is

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Amount of exposure of default towards 3 counterparties}
        {\centering (with netting and collateral agreement)\par}
        \label{1}
        \begin{tabular}{|c | c| c|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{lightgray}
            Counterparty & Amount of EAD & Amount of EAD\\
            \rowcolor{lightgray}
                         & (with netting) & (no netting)\\
            \hline  
            A & \$29,637,720 & \$92,604,560 \\
            B & \$38,250,400 & \$107,949,900\\
            C & \$124,619,600 & \$124,619,600 \\
            \hline
            Total&\$192,507,800 & \$325,174,100\\
            \hline          
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a real  full compilable code, not the image of a code fragment.

Comment: Instead of screenshots, please add a MWE that shows your problem.

Comment: @Bernard OK I edit it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is viewer and zoom-level dependent ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW9gj.png) under SUMATRA at 125%; no lines visible; other zoom levels show lines or not).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution with `makecell`. I also improved the caption spacing w.r.t. to table (`caption` package) and added some vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells (`cellspace` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell, cellspace, caption}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \centering\captionsetup{justification = centering}
        \caption{Amount of exposure of default towards 3 counterparties\\ (with netting and collateral agreement)}
        %{\centering}
        \label{1}
        \begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|Sc|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
            Counterparty & \makecell{Amount of EAD\\ (with netting)} & \makecell{Amount of EAD\\ (no netting)}\\
            \hline
            A & \phantom{1}\$\,29,637,720 & \phantom{1}\$\,92,604,560 \\
            B & \phantom{1}\$\,38,250,400 & \$\,107,949,900\\
            C & \$\,124,619,600 & \$\,124,619,600 \\
            \hline
            Total&\$\,192,507,800 & \$\,325,174,100\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]
With the default vertical alignment of `\makecell` (centred), you obtain this, which looks nicer, in my opinion:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. One possible work-around, however, is to use just one row and use a `tabular` for the two-line cells. A new command `\ccell` can be quite handy for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ccell}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Amount of exposure of default towards 3 counterparties}
    {\centering (with netting and collateral agreement)\par}
    \label{1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{lightgray}
        Counterparty & \ccell{Amount of EAD\\(with netting)} & \ccell{Amount of EAD\\(no netting)} \\ \hline
        A & \$29,637,720 & \$92,604,560      \\
        B & \$38,250,400 & \$107,949,900     \\
        C & \$124,619,600 & \$124,619,600    \\      \hline
        Total&\$192,507,800 & \$325,174,100  \\      \hline          
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I propose an alternate solution, following [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98122/89949), which makes no use of vertical separators. I had to reduce by `1pt` the vertical separation among columns and also the horizontal separation among the colored rows.

I used `booktabs` rules, and I used `\addlinespace[0pt]` to put the toprule exactly on the grey cells, without separation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Amount of exposure of default towards 3 counterparties}
        {\centering (with netting and collateral agreement)}
        \label{1}
        \begin{tabular}{c!{\vrule width -1pt}c!{\vrule width -1pt}c}
            \toprule\addlinespace[0pt]
            \rowcolor{lightgray}
            Counterparty & Amount of EAD & Amount of EAD\\[-1pt]
            \rowcolor{lightgray}
                         & (with netting) & (no netting)\\[2pt] 
            A & \$29,637,720 & \$92,604,560 \\
            B & \$38,250,400 & \$107,949,900\\
            C & \$124,619,600 & \$124,619,600 \\
            \midrule
            Total&\$192,507,800 & \$325,174,100\\
            \bottomrule          
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

with this result:

[image]

Also, I feel you could totally avoid the top rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Amount of exposure of default towards 3 counterparties}
        {\centering (with netting and collateral agreement)}
        \label{1}
        \begin{tabular}{c!{\vrule width -1pt}c!{\vrule width -1pt}c}
            \rowcolor{lightgray}
            Counterparty & Amount of EAD & Amount of EAD\\[-1pt]
            \rowcolor{lightgray}
                         & (with netting) & (no netting)\\[2pt] 
            A & \$29,637,720 & \$92,604,560 \\
            B & \$38,250,400 & \$107,949,900\\
            C & \$124,619,600 & \$124,619,600 \\
            \midrule
            Total&\$192,507,800 & \$325,174,100\\
            \bottomrule          
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's better with no white strip!

Comment: @CarLaTeX I feel that the toprule has some whitespace around it. As you can see the second table is better, I don't think that the top rule serves much purpose anyway since the header is already highlighted

Comment: @CarLaTeX Of course I will, but I'm at work now...

Comment: @CarLaTeX better now?

Comment: Much better now :)

Comment: This did not generate the gray color on my end

Answer (score 3):

Also with `makecell` and (off-topic) `siunitx` for `S` column type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \captionsetup{justification = centering}
\caption{Amount of exposure of default towards 3 counterparties\\ (with netting and collateral agreement)}
    \label{1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{2}{>{\$\,}S[table-format=9.0,
                                 group-separator={,},
                                 table-align-text-pre=false,
                                 table-space-text-pre={\$\,}
                                 ]|}
                }
    \hline
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
Counterparty 
    &   {\thead{Amount of EAD\\ (with netting)}} 
        &   {\thead{Amount of EAD\\ (no netting)}}   \\
    \hline
A   &    29 637 720 &    92 604 560                     \\
B   &    38 250 400 &   107 949 900                     \\
C   &   124 619 600 &   124 619 600                     \\
    \hline
Total
    &   192 507 800 &   325 174 100                     \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Good idea to use `siunitx`. I was too tired to write it, and I did the alignment by hand, but yours is neater.